# Example of a library : TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: numpy, typeerror

While using an example of a library, i got this error :  TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Anyone knows this issue please ?

Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, which library and provide a small example of your code to see why it happens.

Comment: There are many ways this error can be generated.  Please  provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates how you got this error.

Comment: Here's a tip. If you google the exact wording of the error that you have in your title, I'm sure you'll land on a SO question that 99% explains why you got it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.